# How do I read multiple things from a text file into C++

Tags: c++

I have an assignment for a class where I have to read in the name of an item, it's weight, and then price. How do I create a while loop to store each individual element into a string, and two doubles respectively?

Example from text file:

Bananas

1.31

0.99

Rib Eye Steak

2.55

14.96

Chicken Breast Value Pack

7.85

21.97

Dry Dog Food

20.00

14.99

Apples

2.50

3.49

Comment: try something, show us what you tried, if you cant even start then you should go back to your instructor

Comment: You could use a counter which is initially set to 0 and which increases each time you process a line.Assume you have a file: `std::ifstream file("filename.txt")` and a `std::string str` which will sequencially hold each line of the file.Loop through the file: `while(std::getline(file, str))` and now you have to check whether the line you have just read is a string or a double. This is the counter part: if `counter % 3 == 0` then you have just read the product name, if `counter % 3 == 1` then the string is the weight and so on. Increment counter; convert string to double using sstream

Comment: Show us your work and let us know where you are stuck. This community is here to help but not here to do your homework. Look at [How to ask a good question in Stack overflow](https://www.google.ca/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiMm9-VjLvQAhVV9WMKHXtQAGgQFggdMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fhelp%2Fhow-to-ask&usg=AFQjCNEDXp3Jt0aiEKFPFI03PFSjhs3gAw&sig2=MjWNvi_tIvs-_NjGrK445w&bvm=bv.139250283,d.cGc) for more help.

Comment: Im not trying to get you guys to do any work for me I was just stuck on that aspect their is more to the assignment... I am new to Stack and I don't know how to link my code if you can show me I will edit in what I already have.

Answer (score -2):

you can do a for loop that goes to the next character and it puts it into a variable until it hits a space and when that happens it puts that into a array until it's done. and you can do everything you want to  that and after that I don't know anything c++ but that's it.

```
var out1 = "";

var out = [];

for (var i =0; i<(the-file).length; i++) {if ((the-file)[i]=" ") {

out=[out,out1];

var out1 = "";

} else {

out1=out1+(the-file)[i]
   }
}
```

and (the-file) is the test input or the file you are using. out is the array out that you want to do stuff with and you may have to mess with it because it will probability not work

Comment: C++ don't have thing like `var`